# Output Kivy video sound to 3.5mm jack

Tags: audio, hdmi, gstreamer

I'm trying to play a video with sound using Kivy video. When the Pi is attached to a 7" touchscreen it plays the soundtrack from the audio jack as expected. However, when attached to a VGA or DVI monitor/projector using HDMI converter there's no sound from the jack.

I've tried

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

on console and

```
 hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1
```

in the R.Pi config file but neither had any effect. I assume it's Kivy's version of gstreamer which is trying to play audio via the HDMI port.

Any ideas?

Let me know if you want anymore information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot be done (at least not easily), also recent Raspberry Pi updates seem to have broken kivy videoplayer and audio modules as in the audio is very distorted and videos play very slowly.

The videoplayer was replaced by an omxplayer overlay which additionally allows for hardware acceleration.